# placing text using \widthof with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, scaling, parameters

I am new to using Tikz and I do have a question about writing a macro with allows me to use a parameter to scale a simple drawing and put text according to the size of the drawing.

Here is what I would have used in a old-fashioned LaTeX picture environment:

```
\newcommand{\wtb}[2][4]{
\setlength{\unitlength}{#1mm}
\raisebox{-#1mm/4}{\begin{picture}(1,1)
\put(0,0){\line(1,0){1}}
\put(0,0){\line(0,1){1}}
\put(1,0){\line(0,1){1}}
\put(0,1){\line(1,0){1}}
\put(#1mm-\widthof{\mbox{\tiny$#2$}},\heightof{\mbox{\tiny$#2$}}){\makebox(0,0){\mbox{\tiny$#2$}}}
\end{picture}\,}
```

Now if I use Tikz, the drawing and scaling can still be done, but when I try to put the text the \widthof and \heightof commands produce errors. Here is what I tried:

```
\newcommand{\wtb}[2][4]{
\raisebox{-#1mm/4}{
{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[line width=1pt] (0,0) -- ++(#1mm,0) -- ++(0,#1mm) -- ++(-#1mm,0) -- cycle;
\draw (#1mm-\widthof{\mbox{\tiny$#2$}},\heightof{\mbox{\tiny$#2$}}) node {\mbox{\tiny$#2$}};
\end{tikzpicture}\,}
```

What is the correct (good) way to do such things in Tikz? Any help much appreciated.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436). While code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

This is especially important for `tikz` as there are numerous libraries.